# "System" process High CPU usage (ntoskrnl.exe)

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, high-cpu-usage

From time to time the system process takes a lot of CPU, this causes my computer to freeze and lasts for a few seconds (5-10s). Mostly happens when playing games, while playing it happens every few minutes, otherwise very very rarely and if it does, it doesn't take more than 5% CPU.

I used Process Explorer and found out, that this process is causing it: `ntoskrnl.exe!KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLock0x94`

[image: ntoskrnl in task manager]

I found, that it has something to do with drivers, but I'm not sure what to do. There aren't many threads on this issue and I need help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your computer model and network adapter model?

Comment: @harrymc There's a lot of adapters, which one do I choose? (I'm using system information -> components -> network)

Answer (score 0):

That's your computer kernel, sadly this is a really big problem many users have, The only way to fix it is to repair your pc by: Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
Choose your language settings, and then click “Next”.
Click “Repair your computer.” Otherwise, there might be ways to do it using with Safe Mode, The computer kernel is for handling drivers and etc.

Comment: Oh thanks, I don't have any installation disc though. This computer is very old, so I'm scared of losing my files. Is it possible to use the .iso image from Microsoft and burn it on a cd somehow?

Comment: I wouldn't take chances with a very old computer.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad - If you have the .iso from Microsoft you can burn it on a cd, using many apps, most  popular free app is **PowerISO**:http://www.poweriso.com

Comment: Windows can burn an iso without additional software.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with the temperature.

You may use for example [Core Temp](https://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/)
to display the CPU temperature on the taskbar.

For a very old computer, the best thing you can do is cleanup.
Other methods, like replacing the thermal paste might be dangerous.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply, I've checked the temperature. 40-50°C normally, 50-70°C when playing games. Is that fine?

Comment: That's even low for a game. I understand you're using Process Explorer. The next time this happens, select the thread with the high CPU and click the Stack button. Add the screenshot of it to your post.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, I wasn't home. So, when I click "Stack" it says "Unable to access thread". Same in administrator mode.

Comment: Lol it's definitely a problem with the temperature. My laptops is HOT because of this damn thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Ntoskrnl.exe process](https://softwaretested.com/files/what-is-ntoskrm-exe-error/) (Windows NT operating system kernel executable) is responsible for multiple system services, such as hardware abstraction, process and memory management. According to other forums, this is most likely due to [memory issues](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/ntoskrnlexe-causing-crashes-and-bsod-even-in-safe/73055535-78e0-417e-9b64-d9c91bc7997b) on your computer. Try performing a Memtest to check your RAM's health.